# Corona sdk - Touch issues going to next scene into webView

Tags: webview, lua, touch, coronasdk, scene

Using Sublime to work in with the Corona sdk Simulator. I install each apk into my phone to test.

I am very new to Corona sdk and Lua and have been reading questions and answers, some have helped and I still just can't get this particular transition right. What I'm trying to do is take a web app that we already have and open after the welcome page using webview. I am gaining more understanding the more I spend time with it but would appreciate some help on where I might be going wrong?

I get the first page to show with my logo and the listener seems to be working. But when I install it on my Android GalaxyS3 The touch does not work and nothing happens. Here is the code I'm working with.

I'm not sure if its just a couple lines I may be off or just way off completely.  I have also opened up permission within the build for the network to be accessed. Thanks for your help. I'm wanting my logo to be the button that opens the scene or a swipe which I need to research. For some reason I can't get the touch to work and take me past the first welcome screen. I have three files I'm working with. *main.lua*, *config.lua*, and *build.lua*. All of this code is out of *main*.

```
local myTextObject = display.newText( "Welcome to", 320, 110, "Arial", 60)
local Btn = display.newImage( "logo-final-blackbkg-stacked-otl.png" )
Btn.x = 320; Btn.y = 530;

local myListener = function( webview )
    print( "Listener called with event of type: touch"..webview.name )
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", myListener )
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", myListener )

function Btn:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( "Event dispatched; Btn: scene")
    end
    return true
end

local function myTouchListener()

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        --code executed when the button is touched

local playBtn;
local exitBtn;

local function onPlayBtnRelease()
    composer.gotoScene( "main", "fade", 500)
    return true
end

local function onExitBtnRelease()
    composer.gotoScene("main", "fade", 500)
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
local webview = require "webview"


function scene:create ( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

webview:addwebListener("requestUrl", webview)
scene:addEventListener("create", scene)
end

function scene:show ( event )


    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will") then
        elseif (pase == "did") then

local socket = require("socket")

--Connect to the client
local client = socket.connect("www.stockmashin.com",  80)
--Get IP and Port from client
local ip, port = client:getsockname()

--Print the ip address and port to the terminal
print("IP Address: ") 

end

native.newWebView( centerX, centerY, width, height )

local function webListener( event )
    if event.url then
        print( "You are visiting: www.stockmashin.com" .. event.url )
    end

    if event.type then
        print( "The event.type is www.stockmashin.com" .. event.type ) -- print the type of request
    end

    if event.errorCode then
        native.showAlert( "Error!", event.errorMessage, { "OK" } )
    end
end

local webView = native.newWebView( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 320, 480 )
webView:request( "http://www.stockmashin.com/" )

webView:addEventListener( "urlRequest", webListener )
local availableChannel = audio.findFreeChannel()
        print( "object touched = myButton"..tostring(event.target) )  --'event.target' is the touched object
    end
    return false  --prevents touch propagation to underlying objects
end 

function scene:destroy( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view

   -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
   -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
   -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

return scene

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have three things going on that you need to fix.

First, unless you are very comfortable with how Composer works, you should simply assume that main.lua can never, ever be a scene.  It's just a starting point to load your first scene:

```
 local composer = require("composer")
 --
 -- other initialization code
 --
 composer.gotoScene("yourfirstsceen").
```

Then in yourfirstscene.lua (you can rename it whatever makes sense, perhaps "menu.lua", you take the existing scene template and copy it verbatim.  Don't take out any parts.  Do this for each scene, starting with the scene template as your basis.

Next, your display objects should be created inside the scene's **scene:create( event )** function.  Each object after being created must be added to the scene's view group:

```
 sceneGroup:insert(yourNewDisplayObject)
```

The exception to this and third issue is that native objects like newWebViews' (anything that starts with native.*) is not part of the Corona SDK OpenGL canvas display hierarchy and cannot interact with Corona SDK drawing API's (like creating a new image, adding it to a group, etc.).  These always sit on top of the Corona SDK OpenGL canvas.  You must create them in the scene's **scene:show( event )** function so that they will not look weird during scene transitions.  You must them manually remove them in the scene's **scene:hide( event )** function.  If you do not they will stay on the screen.